# Map values from one DataFrame to another

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames:

- `df` - the core DataFrame with columns/cells that I want to expand
- `maptable` - a maptable DataFrame that maps certain columns

An example:

```
maptable:

id | period
A  | winter
B  | summer
A  | summer
nan | summer
B  | nan

df:

id | period  | other_col
A  | None    | X
B  | summer  | Y
C  | None    | Z
D  | spring  | D
D  | NaN
```

How can I only map the cells in df that are None/empty/nan using the maptable and the identifier column id?

Comment: What would be the expected output you are looking for?

Comment: `df['period'].fillna(df['id'].map(maptable.set_index('id')['period']))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and then  fill `NaN` with [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['period']= df['period'].fillna(df['id'].map(maptable.set_index('id')['period']))   
#alternative
#df['period']= (df['id'].map(maptable.set_index('id')['period'])
#                       .where(df['period'].isnull(),df['period']))
```

**Output**

```
  id other_col  period
0  A         X  winter
1  B         Y  summer
2  C         Z     NaN
3  D         D  spring
```

**EDIT [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)**

```
new_df= (df.merge(maptable,on = 'id',how = 'left')
           .assign(period = lambda x: x['period_x'].fillna(x['period_y']))
           .loc[:,df.columns])
print(new_df)
  id  period other_col
0  A  winter         X
1  A  summer         X
2  B  summer         Y
3  C     NaN         Z
4  D  spring         D
```

Comment: What is the difference with the alternative?

Comment: then we need merge

Comment: Does this also wrok with x['period_x'] as my col name might be dynamic

Comment: it is the same, you can select the suffix

Comment: I am receiving the error ['period'] not in index in my dataset

Comment: columns in example are the same than originals DataFrame?

Comment: I redescribed the problem in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60167631/iterative-left-merge-only-on-empty-values-from-a-maptable-to-a-df-in-pandas

Answer (score 1):

```
# Creating your dataframes
maptable = pd.DataFrame([{"id":"A","period":"winter"},{"id":"B","period":"summer"}])
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":["A","B","C","D"], "period":[None, "summer", None, "spring"], "other_col":list('XYZD')})

# Merging both dataframes on the "id" key
df1 = pd.merge(left=df, right=maptable, on="id", how="left")
df1["period"] = [x if not pd.isnull(x) else y for x, y in zip(df1["period_x"], df1["period_y"])]
df1.drop(["period_x", "period_y"], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df1)
```

**Output:**

```
  id other_col  period
0  A         X  winter
1  B         Y  summer
2  C         Z     NaN
3  D         D  spring
```

Comment: How does this work with duplicate indices in the maptable?