# Left merge on slice pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for an iterative way to append values from a maptable to my df of reference. In a simple form, this can be achieved using a left merge.

The challenge that I am facing are:

- The new column might already be present in my df (but containing empty values)
- There might be duplicate indices (eg id1 has two times 1 ans two times 2)
- In each iteration, I only want to fill the empty values in df (column `col_to_map`)

To give you an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df_dict = dict({
    'id1': [1, 2, 3, None, 1, 2],
    'id2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', None, None],
    'val1': [None, None, None, None, None, None],
    'val2': ['21a', None, None, None, None, None]
})

map_dict = dict({
    'id1': [5, 4, 3, 5, pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan],
    'id2': ['e', 'd', None, None, 'b', None],
    'val1': ['15e', '14d', '13c', '15e', '12b', 'x1'],
    'val2': ['25e', '24d', None, None, None, 'x2'],
    'val3': ['35e', '34d', '33c', None, '32b', None],
})

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
maptable = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(map_dict)

for id_col in ['id1', 'id2']:
    for col_to_map in ['val1','val2','val3']:

        print(f'map {col_to_map} using id {id_col}')
        # logic here to append only the non-empty values
        df = map_iteration(df=df, maptable=maptable, id_col=id_col, col_to_map=col_to_map)
```

---

**WHAT I TRIED AND WHERE I AM STUCK**

I tried the following for `map_iteration()`, but I receive the error "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis":

```
def map_iteration(df, maptable, id_col, col_to_map):
    """Map empty values in df col_to_map using the maptable and on the id_col"""

    # Add column to df
    if col_to_map not in df:
        df.insert(len(df.columns), column=col_to_map, value=None)

    # Take out invalid ids in maptable
    maptable = maptable[~maptable[id_col].isnull() & ~maptable[id_col].isna()]
    maptable = maptable[~maptable[id_col].duplicated(keep='first')]

    # Target rows
    elig_rows = df.loc[:, col_to_map].isnull() & ~df.loc[:, id_col].isnull() & ~df.loc[:, id_col].isna()

    # To string ids
    df.loc[:, id_col] = df.loc[:, id_col].astype(str).str.strip()
    maptable.loc[:, id_col] = maptable.loc[:, id_col].astype(str).str.strip()

    # Strip maptable
    m = maptable.loc[:, [id_col, col_to_map]]

    # Merge
    df_left = df.loc[elig_rows, [id_col]].merge(m, how='left', on=id_col)

    # Indexing
    df_left = df_left.set_index(id_col)
    df = df.set_index(id_col)

    # Assign
    df.loc[df.index[elig_rows], col_to_map] = df_left.loc[:, col_to_map]

    # Drop index
    df = df.reset_index()

    return df
```

Comment: it's still not completely clear what you need - for the dummy data, can you show the expected result please?

Comment: I want that the `df` gets populated for the column/rows `val1`, `val2`, `val3` based on the id columns `id1` and `id2`. While this is straightforward to do with a simple left merge, the issue is that I only want to iteratively fill or merge the cell values that are empty or None.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with a solution:

```
for x in df.columns.values:
    for ix, val in enumerate(df[x].values): 
        if not df[x].values[ix]:
            df.at[ix, x] = maptable[x].values[ix]
```

returns:

```
    id1 id2 val1 val2  
0   1.0 a   15e  21a  
1   2.0 b   14d  24d  
2   3.0 c   13c  None  
3   5.0 d   15e  None
```

Still not the most elegant solution tough, someone can come up with a list comprehension of looping simultaneously two columns of df etc.

Well if this is too cumbersome (and yes it is), one solution may be to finding all null values in your df and fill the nulls with the exact correspondences from the in the map table. 
such as:

```
# Find null places in df   
nulls = np.array(df.isnull())
# Find indexes and columns of this null cells   
row_ind, col_ind = np.where(nulls ==True )    
# Fill them  
df_cols = df.columns.values
for ix, col in enumerate(col_ind):
    df.at[row_ind[ix], df_cols[col]] = maptable[df_cols[col]].values[row_ind[ix]]
```

still returns:

```
    id1 id2 val1    val2  
0   1.0 a   15e 21a  
1   2.0 b   14d 24d  
2   3.0 c   13c None  
3   5.0 d   15e None
```

Comment: How do I apply this on my dataset? Here it seems it loops over all cols and ids

Comment: yes, you're absolutely right, you may find all null cells in your df and fill them from map df in exact places. I updated the answer in accordance. I hope it helps. @JohnAndrews

Comment: Why do you loop over all columns?

Comment: Well I do not, it will be more clear if you debug and see for yourself.