# Python: Get ID value of the NA value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have Id column , name and age
I want to get the ID value from ID column of the NA value in Name column , how can I do that with python ?
I was thinking of using a for loop to get the index of NA then find index of ID but I thought maybe there is an easier way

```
A = [["1091",'tom', 25], ["192",'krish', 30],
       ["138",'nick', 26], ["120","",20],["32",'juli', 22],["99","",19]]

B = [["1091","ALEX"], ["192","SAM"],
       ["138",'JACK'], ["120","MAT"],["99","LISA"]]
       
dfA = pd.DataFrame(A, columns =['ID','Name', 'Age'])
dfB = pd.DataFrame(B, columns =['ID','Name'])
dfA = dfA.replace("",np.nan, regex=True)
print(dfA)
```

**output dfA**

```
  ID     Name     Age
0  1091   tom    25
1  192  krish    30
2  138   nick    26
3  120    NaN    20
4  32    juli    22
5  99    NaN    19
```

Comment: Do you mean like `dfA['Name'] = dfA['Name'].fillna(dfA['ID'].map(dfB.set_index('ID')['Name']))`? Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60116654/15497888) by [ansev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11884237/ansev)

Comment: Where do these ID numbers come from? In your provided DataFrames the ids are `[1091, 192, 138, 120, 32, 99]`.

Comment: @HenryEcker sorry I forgot to edit the df (I'm editing it now)

Comment: for example row 4 & 6 in column name have NA values they're associated with ID number 4 & 6 I want to get these values (120&99)

Comment: So just like `print(dfA.loc[dfA['Name'].isna(), 'ID'])`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want the output printed but you can use `np.where` to find the indexes as seen below.

```
select_indices = list(np.where(dfA.loc[:,"Name"].isnull()))
for item in select_indices[0]: #select_indices is an array, you need to access the first element to print the indexes
    print(item)
```

### EDIT

If you want the table rows where the NaN values are use this. You can also specify just the column "ID" instead of ":" if you only want that column.

```
select_indices = list(np.where(dfA.loc[:,"Name"].isnull()))[0]
dfA.loc[select_indices,:] #specify column here
```

If you want literally just to print the 120 and 99 use:

```
select_indices = list(np.where(dfA.loc[:,"Name"].isnull()))[0]
for row in dfA.loc[select_indices,"ID"].iteritems():
    print(row[1])
```

Comment: for example row 4 & 6 in column name have NA values they're associated with ID number 4 & 6 I want to get these values (120&99)